# How do I run a URL whithout opening the browser in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` to run a URL, but every time I execute the function, it opens a new browser tab. How can I just access the link without open the browser?

Comment: Maybe this can help you [wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) for Windows

Comment: Trying to explain it in more details, I have a web server, with some buttons to control things in my house, like turn lights on and off, for example. In visual studio I have an application to access the links of the buttons by voice commands, but for each command I execute,Visual studio opens a browser tab. I just want to send a http request to the server, without open the browser.

Comment: Look at this post for [Http Get & Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to just access a URL without needing any interaction (i.e. just do a HTTP Get), then I think you should probably use [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?view=netframework-4.8).

Basically, instead of calling `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`, you do this:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  var result = wc.DownloadString(url); //where url is the url you intend to access
}
```

Depending on your usage scenario, you may want to call the `wc.DownloadStringAsync` if you do not want to hold up the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed!!